# Centos Ram Issue

Tags: apache, http, memory, centos, ram

Its occupy ram memory server getting slow

PID USER      PR   NI VIRT  RES SHR  s %CPU  %MEM  TIME+   COMMAND

```
14947 apache    20   0  367m  40m 5408 S  0.0  0.1   0:04.21 /usr/sbin/httpd                                                                   
14930 apache    20   0  367m  40m 5200 S  6.3  0.1   0:05.08 /usr/sbin/httpd                                                                   
14941 apache    20   0  367m  40m 4912 S  0.0  0.1   0:05.00 /usr/sbin/httpd                                                                   
14971 apache    20   0  367m  40m 4624 S  0.0  0.1   0:05.89 /usr/sbin/httpd                                                                   
14970 apache    20   0  367m  40m 4720 S  0.0  0.1   0:04.61 /usr/sbin/httpd                                                                   
14938 apache    20   0  461m  39m 4692 S  0.0  0.1   0:04.38 /usr/sbin/httpd                                                                   
14944 apache    20   0  367m  39m 4576 S  0.0  0.1   0:04.81 /usr/sbin/httpd                                                                   
14937 apache    20   0  367m  39m 4540 S  0.0  0.1   0:04.49 /usr/sbin/httpd                                                                   
14954 apache    20   0  461m  39m 4668 S  7.0  0.1   0:04.78 /usr/sbin/httpd                                                                   
14955 apache    20   0  365m  38m 4676 S  0.0  0.1   0:04.92 /usr/sbin/httpd                                                                   
14936 apache    20   0  458m  37m 4624 S  0.0  0.1   0:04.54 /usr/sbin/httpd                                                                   
14935 apache    20   0  363m  36m 4952 S  6.0  0.1   0:04.50 /usr/sbin/httpd
```